# fire on this jquery

Tags: jquery, action

I have the following Jquery code what is just 40% functional. I have couple of product modules generated dynamically with php. Each containing the select combo box and selecting an option should fire on my jquery code, but unfortunately is it executed just in the case of the first module.

```
    <div class="ajax_bar">

            <select id="ajax_call" size="1" name="Weitere Produkte">
                <option value='50'>Weitere Produkte</option>
                <option value='100'>weitere 100</option>
                <option value='150'>weitere 150</option>
            </select>

        </div>    

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#ajax_call").change(function(){
        var domain = document.domain;
        var count = $('#ajax_call :selected').val();
        var $parent = $(this).closest(".product_box");
        var modul_title = $("h4", $parent).text();
});
```

Comment: If I've understood you correctly, then the problem is that you have multiple elements with the ID "ajax_call". If that's the case, change it to a class name instead. ID values have to be unique in a document.

Comment: Your `}` and `)`'s aren't balanced.

Comment: Thanks a lot James this was!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the same ID generated for each combo box in other modules. I think that is probably why only the first one is executed. You can use a class in stead of the id to trigger the change event.

```
   <select class="ajax_call" size="1" name="Weitere Produkte">
  $(".ajax_call").change(function(){})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong. Selecting with an ID will work for only one element. Use class for a generic selection. You should have the select element inside the div with class ajaxbar.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ajax_bar select").change(function(){
       var item=$(this);
       var domain = document.domain;
       var count = item.val();
       var $parent = item.closest(".product_box");
       var modul_title = $("h4", $parent).text();
       alert("count : "+count)
    });
});
```

This will work with **n** number of HTML markup same as you provided(Assuming you are using a unique ID for each select element. If not you should. **ID's should be unique** for elements)

JsFiddle sample  http://jsfiddle.net/AZAZn/5/